# SQL phpmyadmin backup issue

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Our website is hosted by dreamhost and two years ago we switched from joomla to WordPress.

Problem: there is a table (Jo's_bannertrack) with 28.000.000 records (yes seriously). I am pretty sure it's not used anymore, it should be joomla's...but since the website is big and visited, I don't want to make any trouble at all.
I can't make any kind of backup: I have tried with wpclone and with mysql dump but it's always too big.

Dreamhost grants me access with ssh and phpmyadmin.

Any idea?

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2028823 (You can also turn off writes to this table in the [banner configuration](https://docs.joomla.org/Help15:Screen.banners.15). I'm not convinced this is a great place to ask about this Joomla feature, though, as it's not really a programming question.)

Comment: @Matt I don't think it's the joomla feature he's asking about, but making a backup of the big database, so I flagged it to move to dba-stackexchange

Comment: @davejal Seems reasonable. Everything I can see about this table says that nobody will care if it's truncated as long as nobody's monitoring banner click statistics on the site, though, so I figured I'd point out a couple of resources along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these options described in the other stack forums?

1. [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/274659/how-to-backup-big-mysql-database-on-linux)
2. [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database)

Although you haven't given a size of your table (only record count), I expect you should be able to do a simple mysqldump (using your ssh login) at least from that specific table only.

You could also define the amount of rows to backup by using your phpmyadmin

1. Browse to the table and open to view the records
2. Click on export
3. On the buttom "Save as file" use the option to select how many rows to export and starting at.

This will output different sql files what your data from 1 table. You should test to see how many rows you can export at a time.

Comment: Please don't cross post between the various stack sites.

Comment: @Dean I flagged it to move it to DBA, should I edit my answer and remove the beginning?

Comment: certainly when (if) it gets moved to dba it's worth removing but it's not like you said "hey go post this on all the sites" so it's probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

I guess phpMyAdmin is not a kind of tool that can back up so much data effectively. Using some alternate solutions to migrate with such a bulk of data seems quite more reasonable, due to lack of any automation in phpMyAdmin.